# cdo showname displays different variables than ncdump

Tags: netcdf, nco, cdo-climate

I am confused why cdo and ncdump display different variables.  I have found that WRF data does not have a coordinate variable of time, like typical ncfiles (http://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Applications/wrfnetcdf.shtml)  .  So I have added a time variable to all of my nc files, and maybe the way I have added this time variable is a reason it is not appearing in cdo showname?   (This is the same question as before, just hopefully clearer wording)

time variable is displayed here with ncdump:

```
$ ncdump -h rotated_UVwinds.nc 
netcdf rotated_UVwinds {
dimensions:
time = UNLIMITED ; // (4 currently)
x = 83 ;
y = 94 ;
variables:
    double time(time) ;
    float latitude(y) ;
    float longitude(x) ;
    float Vearth(time, y, x) ;
    float Uearth(time, y, x) ;
}
```

There is no time variable shown here with cdo:

```
$ cdo showname rotated_UVwinds.nc 
latitude longitude Vearth Uearth
cdo showname: Processed 4 variables ( 0.00s )
```

Comment: `time` is a dimension, and not a variable. `cdo showname ...` just shows variables, i.e., `x` and `y` also do not show up.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two or three steps: rename 't' dimension to 'time'. make it unlimited. add attributes.

```
ncrename -d t,time in.nc
ncks --mk_rec_dmn time in.nc out.nc
ncatted -a standard_name,time,c,o,'time' -a long_name ... out.nc
```

The NCO options are all described in the online manual [here](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html).

Comment: thanks for this comment, this was useful but I think I needed to reword the question to make it clearer what I was asking